# Change ReactPlayer subtitles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

Can I custom or change the font, color, and position for subtitles?

This is my code

```
<ReactPlayer
            playing={true}
            url={myvideo}
            config={{
              file: {
                tracks: [
                  {
                    src: "123.vtt",
                    default: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
            }}
          />
```

Hope you guys understand :D

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can use the property "style" to pass one inline styles to the root element.

https://github.com/CookPete/react-player

Comment: Did it worked for you?